# Apache Rewrite Equivalent to AliasMatch

Tags: apache, alias, virtualhost

As of now my code looks like the following:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName article.example.com
  AliasMatch "^/(.*)" "/var/www/html/article.php"
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName company.example.com
  AliasMatch "^/(.*)" "/var/www/html/company.php"
 </VirtualHost>
```

This simply maps `article.example.com` to `article.php` file. Example: `article.example.com/test` will map to `article.php`. Similar with `company.example.com` which will map to `company.php` file.

I want to include a wildcard domain extension virtual host and have it do the same as the above. Here's the code i've been testing. Can this be achieved?

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.*
  AliasMatch "^article\.*.*/(.*)" "/var/www/html/article.php"
  AliasMatch "^company\.*.*/(.*)" "/var/www/html/company.php"
 </VirtualHost>
```

Do I need to use rewrite engine? *(nonworking example)*

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.*
  AliasMatch "^article\.*.*/(.*)" "/var/www/html/article.php"
  AliasMatch "^company\.*.*/(.*)" "/var/www/html/company.php"
 </VirtualHost>
```

OR *(nonworking example with rewrite engine)*

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.*
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^article\.(.+)$ [NC][OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^company\.(.+)$ [NC][OR]
  RewriteRule ???
 </VirtualHost>
```

**Current Version (*not working*):**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (article|company)\.example\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.example\. $1\.php
```